# UDSONCAN how to apply stmin

Tags: python, can-bus, uds

I'm trying to use udsoncan with function transfer_data() to send a block of CAN TP data.
But the interval time between 2 frame is 0.000254. So how can I expand this time more.

My config is.

```
isotp_params = {
        'stmin': 32,
        # Will request the sender to wait 32ms between consecutive frame. 0-127ms or 100-900ns with values from 0xF1-0xF9
        'blocksize': 8,  # Request the sender to send 8 consecutives frames before sending a new flow control message
        'wftmax': 0,  # Number of wait frame allowed before triggering an error
        'tx_data_length': 8,  # Link layer (CAN layer) works with 8 byte payload (CAN 2.0)
        'tx_data_min_length': None,
        # Minimum length of CAN messages. When different from None, messages are padded to meet this length. Works with CAN 2.0 and CAN FD.
        'tx_padding': 0x00,  # Will pad all transmitted CAN messages with byte 0x00.
        'rx_flowcontrol_timeout': 1000,
        # Triggers a timeout if a flow control is awaited for more than 1000 milliseconds
        'rx_consecutive_frame_timeout': 1000,
        # Triggers a timeout if a consecutive frame is awaited for more than 1000 milliseconds
        'squash_stmin_requirement': False,
        # When sending, respect the stmin requirement of the receiver. If set to True, go as fast as possible.
        # 'max_frame_size': 4095  # Limit the size of receive frame.
}
```

I'm trying to increase stmin but It cannot exand the time